# fancybox closes on clicking other than crossbutton

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox, doctype, mousewheel

Here is the fiddle, The fancybox closes on clicking inside the popup, which is incorrect, It should close on on clicking the cross button at the top right corner and outside the popup. Further when I include the jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js, It throws the doctype error in firebug;

http://jsfiddle.net/refhat/PBAj9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add the following parameter to the fancybox init:

'hideOnOverlayClick':false

Try changing the src of your mousewheel script to:

http://www.fancybox.net/js/fancybox-1.3.4/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js

There seem to be some permissions issues with some of the resources on their servers.

If this doesn't fix it - what issue are you getting in firebug? Permissions is the only problem I can see...

Comment: Thanks, but I still see the firebug error, though I removed double slash in mouse wheel

Comment: Hi Timbo, Thanks that actually fixed the issue, It wasn't going to proper js.
Firebug was Saying:
syntax error
[Break On This Error] <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHT...org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
On a learning note why does it show a doctype error

Comment: Which was probably because the js file url was resolving to an html page due to their server settings. If you get issues like this it's worth copying the url into your browser address bar and checking it resolves to a script.